# php session value lost

Tags: php, session

I have two php files:
page-1.php: creates a session variable
page-2.php: retrieves the session value

I defined session start on top of both files. page-1.php sets the session but page-2.php display nothing, the value is lost.

Here's my code:

page-1.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    // Set session variables
    $_SESSION["animal"] = "cat";

    print "Session variable is set: ".$_SESSION["animal"]."<br />";
    ?>
    <a href="session-2.php">[Retrieve session]</a>
```

page-2.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    print "session value: ".$_SESSION["animal"]."<br />";
    ?>
```

page-1.php returns "Session variable is set: **cat**"
page-2.php returns "session value:" followed by a < br />

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start) returns a boolean which is true if a session was successfully started, otherwise false. You could check that.

Comment: Does the second page display *nothing* or does it display *"session value:"* followed by a `<br/>` element?  Please clarify.

Comment: @david it display "session value:" followed by a <br/> element

Comment: And also make sure that there's no whitespace before the opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: @volkerschulz there's no whitespace before the opening

Comment: @newbie_php Just wanted to make sure, since the code you posted has that indentation.

Comment: Make sure error logging is enabled and then test your code. Then check the PHP error log file for any errors/warnings related to the Session

Comment: Any luck checking whether the session actually started? This code will do that: `echo "Session was" . (session_start() ? "" : " not") . " started.<br>";`. Note that `session_start()` will be evaluated before the string exists and can be echoed.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thanks! I got "Session was not started", so how can I start it?

Comment: The first thing to do is to [check for warnings and error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display).